# Where can I find working code examples of object detection (cars, people) written in OpenCL or CUDA?

Tags: c, cuda, computer-vision, opencl, gpgpu

Where can I find working code of object detection (part of computer vision) written in OpenCL or CUDA?  Greatly appreciate in advance.

Comment: Try being more specific about the kind of objects you are interested in.  Search for something specific, like detection of people, cars, or faces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of demos and papers at nvidia's [Cuda Zone](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_apps_flash_new.html). Search for "detection".

For example:

- Fast Human Detection with Cascaded Ensembles (476d306d-6a77-4749-8210-8b7b19ebd420)
- Detection and Tracking of Human Subjects (608510ce-a512-41c8-b32a-b55cb524284d)
- GPU-Based Road Sign Detection Using Particle Swarm Optimization (76dcd879-098a-41f2-ab03-38c43d2a042e)